When I use the latest version of ksp and hilt, it gives this error
When I use the latest version of ksp and hilt, it gives this error.
ksp = "2.0.0-1.0.22"
hilt = "2.51.1"

I created a new project and updated all Google libraries and use the latest version of gradle.
When using the latest version of Hilt and Ksp, I encounter the following error.
Unable to load class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.buildtools.api.SourcesChanges'
org.jetbrains.kotlin.buildtools.api.SourcesChanges

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

[versions]
ksp = "2.0.0-1.0.22"
hilt = "2.51.1"

[libraries]
hilt-android-compiler = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android-compiler", version.ref = "hilt" }
hilt-android = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android", version.ref = "hilt" }

[plugins]
ksp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = "ksp" }
hilt = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = "hilt" }`


`//gradle project
  alias(libs.plugins.ksp) apply false
  alias(libs.plugins.hilt) apply false

//gradle module
    alias(libs.plugins.ksp)
    alias(libs.plugins.hilt)

dependencies {
    ksp(libs.hilt.android.compiler)
    implementation(libs.hilt.android)
}



Make sure that the version of Kotlin Android Plugin/Kotlin JVM and KSP match. It helped me
Does not compile:
[versions]
kotlin = "1.9.0"
ksp = "2.0.0-1.0.22"

Works:
[versions]
kotlin = "1.9.0"
ksp = "1.9.0-1.0.12"

